# Torch: How to reshape a 4D tensor in 3D one

Tags: visualization, reshape, conv-neural-network, torch

I need to reshape a 4D tensor of dimension a x b x c x d into a list of 3D ones, a * b x c x d. I need them to visualize filters after each convolutional layer, using the following code:

```
 for k,v in pairs(model:findModules('cudnn.SpatialConvolution')) do
   filters = v.weight
   image.save("PathWhereToSave", image.scale(image.toDisplayTensor{input=filters}, 224, 224))
 end
```

Unfortunately, due to the way the tensor are set up I receive this error:

> packed must be a HxW or KxHxW or Kx3xHxW tensor, or a list of tensors

Do you have some suggestion or a better way to do what I need to do?
Thanks in advance